# React native + Crashlytics - Pinpoint exact file name and line number

Tags: react-native, crashlytics, google-fabric

I succeeded in integrating Crashlytics with React Native and I am also getting the stacktrace when the crashlytics.crash() function.

I integrated another module called 'react-native-fabric-crashlytics' to catch the javascript stacktrace.

However, I would like to bring this one step further; making it stating the exact method call that caused the crash.

I saw other post of Github where other users are using stacktrace-beautifier to translate the stacktrace ( native one ) into js-understandable output for easier debugging. But either I am doing something wrong here or the solution is deprecated.

Can anyone of you please let me know if this task is achievable? To log the exact the filename and line number that caused the crash in the javascript side ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this time Crashlytics doesn't support any JavaScript based cross platform solution. This means there isn't a good way to accomplish your goals. You may find a community solution that works for you.

Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, this is the case. I might use BugSnag or will also try exploring microsoft vs app center for react native.